# Get reference to element inside ng-template

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, angular5, ngx-bootstrap-modal

this is my template:

```
<ng-template #template>
    <input #newimg  type="file" class="col-md-10" (change)="fileChange($event)"/>
</ng-template>
```

I cant get reference to `#newimg` when its inside `ng-template`(it works fine if i change `ng-template` to `div`!)

```
@ViewChild('newimg') img: ElementRef; //doesnt work
```

I need to set its value to empty after image uploaded but its always undefined.

Comment: How do you use that `ng-template`?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com `ngx-bootstrap`s modal

Comment: The problem is that bootstrap creates embedded view outside of the component with template, so `@ViewChild` won't work.

Answer (score 4):

`<ng-template>` is not added to the DOM, it exists only in JavaScript code, when the Application runs. Only when it is stamped using for example a structural directive like `*ngFor` or `*ngIf`, the content is actually created in the DOM and bindings, components, directives, ... are instantiated.

Therefore without stamping, there won't be any `#template` to query for.

Comment: but he's passing it to ngx-bootstrap and bootstrap modal creates an embedded view using this template

Comment: Then a parent of that dialog should be able to query it using `@ContentChild('template') ...`.

Comment: there's no content projection involved, the template is passed directly to the `show` method of bootstrap https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals

Comment: If `@ContentChild()` doesn't work, there probably isn't anything that will. What you you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm not the one asking the question :) The problem is that bootstrap creates embedded view outside of the component with template, so `@ViewChild` won't work. If the embedded view using the template was created as a child of the component with template, `@ViewChild` would work

Comment: Sorry, didn't check :D This is what `@ContentChild()` is for. It allows to query for descendants, projected or not, but the querying component has to be an ancestor.

Comment: I need the input's `nativeElement`  in `change` event

Comment: You can use `(change)="fileChange(newimg)"` or `fileChange(event) { event.target... ;}` with your code (`fileChange($event)`)

Comment: `(change)="fileChange(newimg)"` this only works on input on another button `newimg` is undefined.

Comment: There is no mention of a button in your question.

Comment: You could just add a directive to the input that injects a service, then inject the same service to the component that contains the button and use the service to communicate between both.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, _it allows to query for descendants, projected or not_ - no, it's only used for projected nodes

Answer (score 0):

Use ContentChild instead of ViewChild, because your template reference is within a projected content (ngtemplate)

```
@ContentChild('newimg') img: ElementRef;
```

Comment: This does not seem to work unfortunately. I still get 'undefined' for my elements in ng-template