# How to reference an element based on id which is inside an ng-template in Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a button which is inside an `ng-template` tag. How do I reference the button element based on id in ts file?

I'm trying to reference it this way, but I get an undefined error.

Code:

HTML

```
<ng-template #popup >


 <button type="button" #btn id="btn" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary btn-raised" name="button" > Button </button>


</ng-template>
```

TS file

```
@ViewChild('btn') btn: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
   console.log(this.btn);
}
```

Comment: @HameedSyed it doesn't work

Comment: You cannot. You can use a directive, but it depends on what you are trying to do in the first place. Can you explain what you eventually want to do with that button? There might be a more logical solution.

Comment: @Silvermind I need to call Google login using their JS library which has `attachSignin(element)` function for binding the click event to the button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get reference to element inside ng-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47428783/get-reference-to-element-inside-ng-template)

Comment: can you please let me know what you want to do after grabbing reference

Comment: @PranayRana  I need to call Google login using their JS library which has attachSignin(element) function for binding the click event to the button

Comment: @HameedSyed I couldnt find a solution over there, could you explain?

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume you are using if else directive to get to the ng-template, I suggest you use viewchecked instead of init